# stateProvider using htm5Mode cannot GET error

Tags: angularjs, connect-modrewrite

I am using stateProvider with  $locationProvider.html5Mode:

```
    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/cool");  

    $stateProvider
        // Dashboard
        .state('cool', {
            url: "/cool",
            templateUrl: "views/cool.html"
        });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But when I `http://localhost:8080/cool` I will get **`Cannot GET /cool`** error. `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/#/cool` is working correctly.

---

After some research I found out the problem is because of grunt connect. so I added modRoute to route all url to index.html:

```
livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              modRewrite([
                '!\\.\\w+$ /'
              ]),
```

but now the problem is every url like http://localhost:8080/uncool to http://localhost:8080/cool.

Comment: that's normal... angular works with the hashed part of the url, I think that to be able to use html5 mode you should also change some settings on the server

Comment: Have you added the html base tag in the head?

Comment: Yes I have the <base href="/"> tag

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the "base"-tag in your head.

```
<base href="/">
```

Then make sure that your "/cool"-page serves the same thing as your "/". If not, the server will send back 404 (as expected). This has to be true for all your "sub pages".

To test if this is the case – create a link with a href to "/cool", angular should handle this "internally" with a `pushState`, which differs from just "browsing" to that page. Meaning, when you click the link, the page will serve as expected, but if you reload (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), you will get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `html5mode` you have to include `<base>` tag in your `head` part in document. You can set `requireBase` to false and use `html5mode` without `<base>` tag. Please have a look at [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) and [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)